# Consulta de dos registros en una misma tabla SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

Quisiera que me resolvieran esta duda.

Quiero hacer una consulta de una tabla de usuarios, pero quiero hacerla para que me despliegue dos resultados, ya que quiero comparar la información de dos usuarios.

Cuando hago una consulta normal sería así:

```
SELECT * FROM seUser WHERE ID_User = '1'
```

y me despliega la información del usuario con el ID 1.
Ahora, lo que quiero agregar es que la consulta me despliegue también la información del usuario con el ID 23, espero poder haberme explicado bien.

Comment: o sea: `WHERE ID_User IN (1,23)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La consulta larga:

```
SELECT * FROM seUser WHERE ID_User = '1' OR ID_User = '27'
```

y la forma corta (utilizando el [operador IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)):

```
SELECT * FROM seUser WHERE ID_User IN('1','27')
```

*Nota: si el `ID_User` es numerico no debería ir entre comillas.*

Answer (score 0):

en realidad es muy sencillo usa los operadores logicos 
como and "y", or "0", xor "y-o",

ejemplo and
SELECT * FROM seUser WHERE ID_User = '1' and ID_User = '27' 
si existe los dos ID te va a devolver un resultado de los  dos que pides pero si existe solo 1 no te devuelve nada 
ejemplo or
SELECT * FROM seUser WHERE ID_User = '1' or ID_User = '27' 
en este caso realiza lo contrario si existe cualquiera de los dos te trae esa fila sin importar si la otra no existe

Answer (score -3):

Supongo que con hacer dos vistas es suficiente....

> SELECT * FROM seUser WHERE ID_User = '1'
>      SELECT * FROM seUser WHERE ID_User = '23'

...y una vista con las dos opciones...

> SELECT * FROM seUser WHERE ID_User = '1' OR ID_User = '23'